# Flask Blueprint with absolute redirect url

Tags: python, flask

I'm adding OAuth to one of the Blueprints inside a Flask app, and the basic setup for Facebook authentication usually go for something similar to:

```
@app.route('/login')
def login():
    return facebook.authorize(callback=url_for(
        'oauth_authorized',
        next=request.args.get('next') or request.referrer or None)
    )
```

But inside my blueprint, the `url_for` is always returning a relative path URL, like `/auth/oauth_authorized` and is being rejected by Facebook because redirect URLs must be absolute.

I temporarily fixed the issue by hardcoding the redirect URL, but what would be the correct approach to let Flask handle the URL correctly?

Comment: Hm, apparently there's this `_external` argument that forces `url_for` to do what I want. I wonder why is it prefixed with `_` if its use is so convenient.